# Bitbucket API is there a way to return all files in branch?

Tags: c#, git, winforms, bitbucket-api

I'm currently trying to write a windows application that will help automate a website deployment. Since we use BitBucket, I'm using their API.

The problem I have got is that I need to return a list of all the files that have been added/modified in the branch. I see that you can use changeset to get a file manifest, but it only returns the most recent.

For example,
https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{project}/changesets/{hash}

If I remove the hash, it will return the 15 most recent commits, which could be any branch.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bitbucket uses some kind of hash/slug to identify its branches and each branch has a unique slug/hash.

Like in the picture shown below, the hash associated with the branch **company1**  is **1a0560189ab3d1bfa437c8bee9d9521f1ae670e7**.

[image]

Hence, in order to get details of a particular branch, you can use the following URL:

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<company_name>/<repository_name/src/<hash_slug_of_the_branch>/
```

A GET request to the above URL will give you a JSON file that will contain the links to all the files and the folders of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

`/REST/API/1.0/PROJECTS/{PROJECTKEY}/REPOS/{REPOSITORYSLUG}/FILES/{PATH:.*}?AT`

This is a paged API. This API can also be invoked via a user-centric URL when addressing repositories in personal projects.

Retrieve a page of files from particular directory of a repository. The search is done recursively, so all files from any sub-directory of the specified directory will be returned.

Parameter: `at`

the commit ID or ref (e.g. a **branch** or **tag**) to list the files at. If not specified the default branch will be used instead.

Refer to doc: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.7.1/bitbucket-rest.html